# Parsing Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> to Model?

Tags: c#, parsing, expression, linq-expressions

I wanna parse `Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>` to a model :

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Entity> entities = new List<Entity>
        {
            new Entity{ Id = 1, FullName = "Mohammad Dayyan"},
            new Entity{ Id = 2, FullName = "Zahra Ahmadi"},
            new Entity{ Id = 3, FullName = "Milad Ahmadi"},
            new Entity{ Id = 4, FullName = "Ali Dayyan"},
            new Entity{ Id = 5, FullName = "Masoud Ahmadi"},
        };

        //PredicateBuilder is from LinqKit http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx
        Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> predicate2 = PredicateBuilder.False<Entity>();
        predicate2 = predicate2.Or(q => q.Id == 1);
        predicate2 = predicate2.Or(q => q.Id == 3);
        predicate2 = predicate2.Or(q => q.Id == 5);

        Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> predicate1 = PredicateBuilder.True<Entity>();
        predicate1 = predicate1.And(q => q.FullName.Contains("Milad"));

//Predicate3 == {((True AndAlso Invoke(q => q.FullName.Contains("Milad"), f)) AndAlso Invoke(f => (((False OrElse (f.Id == 1)) OrElse (f.Id == 3)) OrElse (f.Id == 5)), f))}
        Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> predicate3 = predicate1.And(predicate2);    

        ExpressionModel model = ParseExpression(predicate3);    

        Console.WriteLine(model);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static ExpressionModel ParseExpression(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> expression)
{

    BinaryExpression binaryExpression = expression.Body as BinaryExpression;
    if (binaryExpression == null) return null;
    Expression left = binaryExpression.Left;
    Expression right = binaryExpression.Right;
    ExpressionModel expressionModel = new ExpressionModel
    {
        NodeType = binaryExpression.NodeType,
        Left = ParseExpression(left),
        Right = ParseExpression(right)
    };
    return expressionModel;
}

static ExpressionModel ParseExpression(Expression expression)
{

    BinaryExpression binaryExpression = expression as BinaryExpression;
    if (binaryExpression == null) return null;
    Expression left = binaryExpression.Left;
    Expression right = binaryExpression.Right;
    ExpressionModel expressionModel = new ExpressionModel
    {
        NodeType = binaryExpression.NodeType,
        Left = ParseExpression(left),
        Right = ParseExpression(right)
    };
    return expressionModel;
}
}


[Serializable]
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ExpressionModel
{
    public ExpressionModel Left { get; set; }
    public ExpressionModel Right { get; set; }
    public ExpressionType NodeType { get; set; }
}
```

But when parser reach to `True` or `Invoke(q => q.FullName.Contains("Milad"), f)` `ParseExpression` method return null!

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this `Invoke(q => q.FullName.Contains("Milad"), f)` is a [MethodCallExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and 
this

```
BinaryExpression binaryExpression = expression as BinaryExpression;
if (binaryExpression == null) return null;
```

returns null, beacuse it is not a BinaryExpression.

Moreover `True` is a ConstantExpression. You need more complex code to parse it and handle all this options.

Try to use this: [metalinq](http://metalinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the response,Do you know any source or libs for parsing an expression?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes, I used it: http://metalinq.codeplex.com/. As I know it converts expressions to serializable EditableExpression. And EditableExpression has method `ToExpression()` which converts it back to Expression.

Comment: I couldn't find Assemblies for download, and the source dosen't open in VS 2012

Comment: @Mohammad Yes it's a little old, but we used it somehow. Ok, I've found this: http://expressiontree.codeplex.com/. This should work on VS2012.